# Which is the best graph to showcase 3 years of data grouped by weekly?

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts, data-visualization

I want to present last 3 years of data grouped on a weekly basis. I have grouped the data in Excel on a weekly basis. I researched and found that a Box plot can be a good way of showing this kind of a data but box plot is inappropriate for this occasion as the team has asked for the number of operations per specialty(for e.g. CAR, RES, GYN etc) per day of the week. I used a line chart to present this data, but it looks too squished due to dates. Is there any other graph that anyone can suggest apart from these two charts? I have attached a snap shot for reference.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you put data for the specialties into separate columns, you can get a chart with a separate line for each specialty. It will be horizontally much less crowded, and you will still see the patterns for each specialty.

[image]

Comment: Will I not end up with many chart? I mean separate charts?

Comment: I've edited my answer to show that my approach plots the data as multiple series in a single chart.

Comment: I have tried it, unfortunately, it doesn't look readable at all. It certainly shows specialties separately in different colours and but looks way too crowded due to data size. I can't post the snapshot of the chart here.